# Cannot install vroom under R.4.0.5 on HPC node

Tags: r, package, hpc, vroom

To install another package that depends on vroom (which failed) on a HPC node, I sought to install vroom manually.

I tried to install the package manually but it fails too:

My code:

```
install.packages("vroom")
```

error message:

```
installing to /home/leuph1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-vroom/00new/vroom/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘vroom’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/leuph1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-vroom/00new/vroom/libs/vroom.so':
  /home/leuph1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-vroom/00new/vroom/libs/vroom.so: undefined symbol: __cxa_init_primary_exception
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/leuph1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/vroom’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘vroom’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpgPcp9Y/downloaded_packages’
```

I have tried under different R versions (3.5.3 up to 4.1.1) but keep having the same issue no matter what version I chose.

I have also deleted any 00LOCK-"package-name" folder that might have arisen in the process in the corresponding R Version package folder, but to no avail.

Can anybody help me out here?

Many thanks in advance,

Philibertus88

Comment: I was having the same issue. Have you tried installing in a vanilla environment? If your HPC uses modules, load the minimal required modules to get R running?